# How to get a list of values with WTForms in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms, werkzeug

In the website I'm building with [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) I'm using [WTForms](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to validate submitted forms. In one form, I'm submitting a list of values with a form like this (the hidden fields are generated client side using js):

```
<form action="" method="post" id="prop-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="ids[]" value="54511ea9c1a36b4e910ce52a">
    <input type="hidden" name="ids[]" value="54511ea9c1a36b4e910ce52d">
    <input id="title" name="title" size="30" type="text" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Save this form">
</form>
```

On the Flask side, I can easily get the contents of `ids[]` using he following code:

```
print request.form
print request.form.getlist('ids[]')
```

prints out:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('ids[]', u'54511ea9c1a36b4e910ce52a'), ('ids[]', u'54511ea9c1a36b4e910ce52d'), ('title', u'Blablabla')])
[u'54511ea9c1a36b4e910ce52a', u'54511ea9c1a36b4e910ce52d']
```

But when I create a `SelectMultipleField` in my wtform as follows:

```
ids = SelectMultipleField('ids[]')
```

and then try to get those values, I get an empty list:

```
print form.ids.data  # prints out []
```

Any idea how I could mimic the behaviour of `request.form.getlist('ids[]')` using WTForms? All tips are welcome!

Comment: I'd think you'd need to use something like `FieldList`

Comment: @Doobeh - I just messed around with that, but I can't get it to work. Would you have an example of it?

Comment: I'm not sure about the `id[]` syntax.  When I use WTF I also use it to generate the form, with `FieldList` it uses `id-1` `id-2` etc.  I answered a similar question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26302943/multiple-instances-of-the-same-form-field/26310776#26310776